# Replace/Substitute but for FORMULA content, not output

Tags: excel-formula

In column A, I sum up a number of cells, all of which are in the same column: e.g. =C1+C6+C9+C32

In column B, I would like to take the formula in column A and automatically replace column C with column D (i.e. D1+D6+D9+D32).

However, all the replace/substitute references I can find only replace characters in the output string and not the formula itself.

Is there another function which does this?

Many thanks! Hashamyim

Tried replace/ substitute and googled for alternative formulae, but everything just comes back either to output-string replacement or just go to Edit>Find+Replace, which isn't automated.

Comment: Why do you need a full column to add four numbers?  when copying A1 to B1, the formula should _autochange_ the `C` to `D`.  (see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y46EH.gif )

Comment: you could use offset, or index

Answer (score 0):

If the formula is in Cell A1, by clicking and dragging the bottom-right box of cell A1 to B1 will input the formula as =(D1+D6+D9+D32) automatically since it is not locked ($D$1+$D$6+...).

Furthermore, if you drag this formula down as well, the row references will shift as well. This is behavior you want to consider when locking your cell references in formulas.

Comment: Sorry, my question was clearly badly formulated! What about if the formula with the 'D' values needs to be in column Z? I would like to find a way of getting the cell to automatically take whatever formula is in column A and replace all cell reference columns in the formula with a different column letter of my choice. The fact that I used columns A->B and C->D in my example was misleading, as it could be any column combination.

Comment: You can use the INDIRECT function, which can look at cells and use the text in those cells to construct your formula. If you wrote "z1" in cell A1, and referenced A1 with the indirect formula it would look at the text in that cell and search z1 for the math.